# Twitter Bootstrap Carousel: Right & Left arrows not working

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

The arrows for BS carousel are not moving the items back and forth

I'm suspecting this might be either a CSS issue or have something to do with the fact that the carousel is being used inside the tabs.

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, it was caused because my page was scroll based so I put in a little script to smooth the scroll of every link which started with `#` . This screwed the left and right buttons because they use `href="#myCarousel"`.
To solve this problem I added an exception to the script like down here.
This is the script before I modified it:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

And I just added an exception with thw href attribute:

```
$(function() {
    $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
        if( $(this).attr("href")=="#myCarousel") return;//This is the exception
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
            var target = $(this.hash);
            target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
            if (target.length) {
                $('html,body').animate({
                    scrollTop: target.offset().top
                }, 1000);
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

This answer is year and a half late but I hope it helps someone else.

edit 3/12/2015:
You can also use the `data-target` attribute instead of `href`

Comment: You sir, are a golden god. A year and a half late, but worked as a charm for me, I used the exact same code as you for smooth scrolling :)

Comment: Thank you so much for adding your answer. I had a same problem and now it is gone - thanks to you.

Comment: Excellent, I had the same smooth scrolling code and the same issue. Thanks!

Comment: "You can also use the data-target attribute instead of href" ....YES that did it for me with Bootstrap 3 :)

Answer (score 3):

Is your HTML formatted like this?

```
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>
  <!-- Carousel items -->
  <div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="active item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
    <div class="item">…</div>
  </div>
  <!-- Carousel nav -->
  <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">&lsaquo;</a>
  <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">&rsaquo;</a>
</div>
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

My Carousel was not working too, and I changed many things. However finally I discover the problem; my problem is smooth scroll and wow.js. Actually, I could not press the prev or next button because of smooth scroll thing. When I try to press button, page is going down or up. Due to that, I change my smooth init and wow init like that.

Smooth Scroll:

```
$(function() {
$('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if( $(this).attr("href")=="#CarouselSlider") return;
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
        var target = $(this.hash);
        target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
        if (target.length) {
            $('html,body').animate({
                scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 900);
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

});

and also Wow.js init:

```
$(document).ready(

function() {

    $("html").niceScroll({
        cursorcolor:"#ba8e16",
        scrollspeed :"100",
        cursorborder:"1px solid #cf9c11",
        horizrailenabled: "false",
        cursorborderradius: "0px"
    });

}
```

);
new WOW().init();

Now, horizontal smooth is over and my problem disappear somehow. I hope, it will help.

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me. Turns out I just had the bootstrap script on the  before the jquery script. Changed this and then it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include boostrap.js after jQuery to make it work. I also found an error for a link to jQuery :

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

should be

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
```

Comment: Bootstrap JS is [already included](http://ztwealth.com.php53-8.ord1-1.websitetestlink.com/assets/js/plugins.js). That jQuery file failing to load is another issue, but there is another jQuery that gets loaded in case jQuery is not loaded from Google.

Comment: Did you initialize the carroussel $('#meet_team_carousel').carousel() ?

Comment: I don't think I need to necessarily initialize it. The class of "carousel" would do the same thing. And as I mentioned, the round white circles (on top right) are working and correctly navigating the items.

Comment: It seems that bootstrap itself is not initiated cause if your try to active it by the console it says "TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'carousel'". Maybe you could have a javascript error that block it.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap depends on jQuery. Check out their [getting-started template](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#template).

Answer (score 0):

Place JQ and your bootstrap.min.js at the bottom of your page just before </body>, like this:

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

Keep in mind you need a version of JQ that works with your version of bootstrap. I'm using bootstrap version 2, so I need JQ 1.11.1